# Why cant I use the generated name for a migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, terminal, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.6

`2018_04_19_095256_create_admins_table.php`, This is the name that
generate when i run the command "php artisan make:migration... "

It does not show on my data base when i run the command "php artisan migrate"
.

But when i change the name of the migration it runs. I change the
 migration name of `"2018_04_19_095256_create_admins_table.php"` to
 `"2014_04_19_095256_create_admins_table.php"`.

Also `"2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php"` didn't show on my database

Is there any way that i can use the generate name for my migration?

Migration file code:

```
Migration table created successfully.

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `admins` add unique `admins_email_unique`(`email`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\century\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\century\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\century\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Paste your migrations files code.

Comment: do you check migrations table? if "2018_04_19_095256_create_admins_table.php" or any names into the table already migrated.

Comment: Check your .env file, this is where you should have your database connection information, next to that make sure to show any errors you come along, Laravel should show some errors in the command line when its unable to migrate.

Comment: @VolkanYılmaz there is no table like "2018_04_19_095256_create_admins_table.php" but when i change it to "2014_04_19_095256_create_admins_table.php" it works. I created almost 3 same artisan command to make mirgration and does not work also

Comment: @killstreet there is no error "DB_CONNECTION=mysql
[DB_HOST=127.0.0.1],
[DB_PORT=3306],
[DB_DATABASE=Century],
[DB_USERNAME=root],
[DB_PASSWORD="]. My data base connection in the .env
. The 3 table are shown on my database but the reset_password didn't show . Those 3 are :"[migration], [admins], [user] " tables

Comment: Do you have a migrations table inside the database?

Comment: @killstreet yes there is "migration => [id,migration,batch]" thats the column of the migration table

Comment: @Troyer the file code edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your AppServiceProvider which will be located at App/Providers and edit it as follow

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

Note We added the use for Schema and added the Schema::defaultStringLength in the boot function. This will remove the error.

Comment: In AppServiceProvider.php line 16:

  Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found